# Specify LayoutParams.flag_secure via xml

Tags: android, xml

I am working on an app which has certain screens which should not allow screenshots to be taken.

I have been able to do it successfully via code.

I have been trying to find out a way to specify LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE for my activity via xml.But no luck

So are there equivalent xml attributes to support this mechanism in activity tag of AndroidManifest.xml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its possible. Moreover, when you specify by code, you must do it in `onCreate` and before calling `super.onCreate`.

Comment: ok. so does this mean that the flag gets applied to a screen before it is actually created..?

Comment: Yes, it applies to the window containing your activity.

Comment: That is certainly not the case. You can set the secure flag in onPause and remove it in onResume (for example). I *just* tested this. But this may not always work, as some vendors mangle the activity code to do other things they desire. So keep that in mind.