# How to disable taking screen shot in android

Tags: android, security, screenshot

How to disable taking screen shot in android . 
My app is inside another container ex: Blackberry container . Im using the blackberry SDK for my app.

Im using the following code:

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

This is not working . 
If there is any solution please provide. Thanks .

Comment: well its not possible have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406316/5110595)

Comment: call code before your setContentView() method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Screen Capture in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android)

Comment: set flags [before super.oncreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17123062/8867002)

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Add this line before your `setContentView()` method.

Description::

**FLAG_SECURE:**
Treat the content of the window as secure, preventing it from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays.

For more details please check android documentation:

[Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: @Jaymin Nice copy paste answer from this post-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android/31406316#31406316,  copycat, try to explain the procedure to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try This solution.

Use WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE before setContentView() mehtod

Note: There is no application level protection. You have to add this code in all the activities that you want to protect.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me , as my app is inside another container app . like blackberry container

Comment: what do you mean blackberry container please explain @madhu